# Search multiple columns for those which start with any of many strings; get counts

Tags: r, regex, count

I have a dataset with 2M observations. I need to search up to 50 character columns to count (and after, filter) which observations start with any of up to 20 strings.

I have written code, which returns the counts for how often each string was found; but it's too slow. Running this on 100k observations (9 columns, 33 search strings) takes 2 minutes, and appears to scale linearly (implying ≈30 minutes for full dataset). I can do this is SAS in seconds and am running on a fast laptop with SSD, so I'm assuming my code is the issue (not the machine or the problem itself).

```
set.seed(42)
df_to_search <- cbind.data.frame(
   "a"=replicate(1e5,paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,1:10),5,replace = T),collapse = "")),
   "b"=replicate(1e5,paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,1:10),5,replace = T),collapse = "")),
   "c"=replicate(1e5,paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,1:10),5,replace = T),collapse = "")),
   "d"=replicate(1e5,paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,1:10),5,replace = T),collapse = "")),
   "e"=replicate(1e5,paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,1:10),5,replace = T),collapse = "")))

search_strings <- c("AB","BC","CD","DE","EF","G6","F8","H1","I9","J7") %>% paste0("^",.) %>% as.vector()

sapply(search_strings, function(y)
  apply(df_to_search, 1, function(x) {
    str_detect(x, y)
  })) %>% colSums()
```

This code yields the following result:

```
^AB ^BC ^CD ^DE ^EF ^G6 ^F8 ^H1 ^I9 ^J7 
394 392 387 389 359 417 397 780 378 382
```

Note: I'm converting the search string to a vector just so that I can pass it to `apply`, which speeds things up by a factor of 3 (vs nested `sapply`). I have tried nested `apply` statements, but it resulted in no speedup. I am also prepending `^` to the search strings as part of regular expression syntax to limit search to start of strings.  I open to entirely different approaches, but I have to be able to search with multiple strings, over multiple columns, for the start of the string, and return the count for each search string.

**EDIT/UPDATE**
These solutions are much faster than mine. Thanks! Unfortunately my example search strings were (unintentionally) misleading. Apologies. My actual search strings are of differing lengths, and sometimes all numbers, anywhere from 2 to 5 characters. I should have used something more like:

```
search_strings <- c("64651","BC","654","DEF","EF","G6","F8","25","I9","J7")
```

I can't think of a way to get the fastest code: `table(substr(unlist...))` to work easily with differing search string lengths, but the `colSums(vapply(...{vapply...}))` works quite well.

Any suggestions with this new information would of course be welcome, but otherwise I think this is answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Just use `table` on `substring()`. It's easy to read, and it's fast.

```
starts <- c("AB","BC","CD","DE","EF","G6","F8","H1","I9","J7")
table(substr(unlist(df_to_search, use.names = FALSE), 1, 2))[starts]
## 
##  AB  BC  CD  DE  EF  G6  F8  H1  I9  J7 
## 394 392 387 389 359 417 397 780 378 382 

system.time(table(substr(unlist(df_to_search, use.names = FALSE), 1, 2))[starts])
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.105   0.000   0.105
```

If you need to eek out even a little bit better timing, you can try `tabulate` instead of `table`. Something like this should work:

```
x <- factor(substr(unlist(df_to_search, use.names = FALSE), 1, 2))
setNames(tabulate(x), levels(x))[starts]
```

### Original answer

I would do the following:

1. Convert the `data.frame` values from `factor` to `character`.
2. Use `startsWith()`, which was introduced in R 3.3

Performance is quite fast.

```
# vector of starts you want to check
starts <- c("AB","BC","CD","DE","EF","G6","F8","H1","I9","J7")

# converting the data.frame to character
df_to_search[] <- lapply(df_to_search, as.character)

# searching and tabulating
colSums(vapply(starts, function(x) {
  vapply(df_to_search, function(y) sum(startsWith(y, x)), integer(1L))
}, integer(ncol(df_to_search))))
#  AB  BC  CD  DE  EF  G6  F8  H1  I9  J7 
# 394 392 387 389 359 417 397 780 378 382
```

---

Here are some timings:

```
starts <- c("AB","BC","CD","DE","EF","G6","F8","H1","I9","J7")
df_to_search[] <- lapply(df_to_search, as.character)
myfun <- function() {
  colSums(vapply(starts, function(x) {
    vapply(df_to_search, function(y) sum(startsWith(y, x)), integer(1L))
  }, integer(ncol(df_to_search))))
} 
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.199   0.000   0.199 

myfun_unlist <- function() {
  temp <- unlist(df_to_search, use.names = FALSE)
  vapply(starts, function(x) sum(startsWith(temp, x)), integer(1L))
}
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.245   0.000   0.245 

cPakfun <- function() {
  sapply(search_strings, function(i) sum(stringr::str_count(unlist(df_to_search), i)))
}
#  user  system elapsed 
# 5.614   0.000   5.613 

cPakfun2 <- function() {
  edited <- paste0("--", starts)
  vec_to_search <- paste0(paste0("--", unlist(df_to_search)), collapse="")
  result <- stringr::str_count(vec_to_search, edited)
  names(result) <- starts
  return(result)
}
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.902   0.000   0.901 

opfun <- function() {
  sapply(search_strings, function(y)
    apply(df_to_search, 1, function(x) {
      str_detect(x, y)
    })) %>% colSums()
}
#   user  system elapsed 
# 44.988   0.000  45.078
```

Benchmarks, in case this is something that you do regularly, rather than just a one-off type of thing:

```
library(microbenchmark)

## Add tabulate to the options
myfun_tabulate <- function() {
  df_to_search[] <- lapply(df_to_search, as.character)
  x <- factor(substr(unlist(df_to_search, use.names = FALSE), 1, 2))
  setNames(tabulate(x), levels(x))[starts]
}

res <- microbenchmark(myfun_tabulate(), myfun_table(), myfun(), myfun_unlist(), cPakfun2())
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  myfun_tabulate()  90.19794 100.2941 120.5411 102.7271 153.4527  238.6175   100
#     myfun_table()  96.87556 110.1965 146.5356 154.3941 168.2660  562.4599   100
#           myfun() 125.68799 127.8053 162.0679 130.0665 182.7757  577.3027   100
#    myfun_unlist() 136.92772 138.4104 170.4002 140.0188 198.8845  613.7919   100
#        cPakfun2() 859.22835 911.5291 940.6695 935.6335 955.3801 1154.5395   100

autoplot(res, log = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't really care about counting by columns, one trick is to `unlist()` your data.frame. This will result in a vector of all values. Then on this vector, you can use `stringr::str_count` to count whether the pattern occurs or not. Then `sum` the result of counts. In short, all the "hard" steps are vectorized and you only need to "loop" over the entries in `search_strings`.

```
sapply(search_strings, function(i) sum(stringr::str_count(unlist(df_to_search), i)))

# ^AB ^BC ^CD ^DE ^EF ^G6 ^F8 ^H1 ^I9 ^J7 
# 394 392 387 389 359 417 397 780 378 382
```

**EDITED** Fully vectorized approach - ~4-5x faster than sapply

You can fully vectorize by converting all your values to a single string with each entry separated by a dummy character, for instance `--`.

```
search_strings <- c("AB","BC","CD","DE","EF","G6","F8","H1","I9","J7")
vec2 <- function() {
    edited <- paste0("--", search_strings)
    vec_to_search <- paste0(paste0("--", unlist(df_to_search)), collapse="")
    result <- stringr::str_count(vec_to_search, edited)
    names(result) <- search_strings
    return(result)
}
vec2()
 # AB  BC  CD  DE  EF  G6  F8  H1  I9  J7 
# 394 392 387 389 359 417 397 780 378 382
```